# Find a subclass in a list

Tags: c#, list, xna

Hi I'm in quite some problem at the moment, I currently have a class "Ship" with subclasses "Player" & "Enemy" both of them are in the List "Ships"

What I'm trying to do is extract the "Player thePlayer" from the list of "Ships"
I've tried using List.Find() without any succes, is it just me using it wrong or is it the wrong way of dealing with this problem?

```
    for (int i = 0; i < HomingBullets.Count; i++)
    {
        HomingBullet h = HomingBullets.ElementAt(i);
        Player thePlayer = ??? List.Find ???
        h.Update(gameTime, thePlayer.position);
    }
```

the h.Update takes the two arguments (gameTime & Vector2)
I'm trying to extract the Vector2 using the code above.

Keep in mind I've only used C# since the start of this year although I have a few years of experience of programming in various languages.

Comment: What does your `Ships` list contain, and what is the logic for finding the player you require?

Comment: the Ships list contains dynamicly changing multiple instances of "Enemy" and a single "Player"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest solution would be to add a readonly property to the `Ship` class:

```
class Ship
{
    public abstract bool IsPlayer { get; }
}

class Player : Ship
{
    public override bool IsPlayer { get { return true; } }
}

class Enemy : Ship
{
    public override bool IsPlayer { get { return false; } }
}
```

Then you could do

```
var thePlayer = (Player)shipList.Find(s => s.IsPlayer);
```

The cast to `Player` could possibly go if you can use that object as a general `Ship` instead of the more specific `Player` (I am assuming that `shipList` is a `List<Ship>`, right?).

Other solutions (such as using the `is` keyword, or the equivalent LINQ `shipList.OfType<Player>().Single()` will work just as well, but checking for runtime type will be much slower than the `IsPlayer` property check.

Comment: Being a `Player` is already modelled in the class hierarchy itself, I'd avoid adding such properties unless necessary for some reason - particularly if they reflected something not modelled directly in the type.

Comment: @Jon: The `IsPlayer` property could be modelled in the hierarchy as well (read-only abstract property on the base class). The idea is that runtime type checks will be *slow*.

Comment: @Jon using your method has me slightly confused the { get; } part, exactly how does that execute ?

Comment: -1 You can (and probably should) use runtime type information for that: if (someVar is Player) ...

Comment: @jv42: I 'd be grateful if you could provide some justification for that?

Comment: Duplicating existing (cheap) information with a (relatively) costly property, that will have to be written in all classes derived from Ship seems a very bad idea.

Comment: @jv42: I think you have it backwards on what is cheap and what is costly. The property access costs as much as a virtual function call, which is pretty low. In fact, the only things that can be cheaper are a non-virtual call and a direct field access. But you don't have to believe me: try measuring. You will find that the existing "cheap" information is 10 to 100 times slower than the "costly" property.

Comment: Well, I haven't done any speed measures, that's right, and I'm coming from a C++ background, where the compiler does some nice things for you. Either way, there is not only the access speed that matters, but also memory usage, amount of code, etc... which also affect performance in the end, and readability of course, less code to read is often better. I'll revert my down vote though, I was a bit hasty there.

Comment: Ah, I thought I could revert it after a while, in fact, it requires an edit, so I can't :(

Answer (score 3):

You can use LINQ's [OfType<>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360913.aspx) operator to return only objects of a specific type from a list or IEnumerable in general. E.g. you can write

```
Ships.OfType<Player>()
```

to return only the instances of type Player.

This is a very inefficient way to search though, as it iterates over all Ships. I suspect that player ships are only a very small percentage of the total ships. It would be better to keep a separate list of Player ships that references the Ship instances in the Ship collection.

Comment: To properly address the OP's question, that should read `Player thePlayer = Ships.OfType<Player>().Single()` or `.First()`

Comment: Yep, this as per Winston's suggestion of adding `Single()` or `First()` is the one to go for (`First()` would be faster, `Single()` if you wanted to consider the case of their being more than one player object as both feasible and incorrect). `FirstOrDefault()` or `SingleOrDefault()` would be better still if there could be no such object (returning null in that case).

Comment: If the list contains only a single Player then the best solution is to store it in a separate variable. Iterating over the entire list each time is very inefficient

Answer (score 1):

`list.Find(sh => sh is Player);`

This is equivalent to creating a method like:

```
bool IsPlayer(Ship sh)
{
  return sh is Player;
}
```

And then iterating through until that method returns true when called on each item (or null if no such item is found.

Answer (score 1):

You can test whether an object is an instance of a given class using the `is` keyword: `x is Player` will be true for your player object and false for the instances of `Enemy` in the list.

It may be better style to define an `isPlayer` method on your `Ship` class (with definitions in `Player` and `Enemy` returning different values), or -- if in fact there's always exactly one `Player` object -- to hold it somewhere else rather than repeatedly looking for it in your list.

Answer (score 1):

Arguably, a much better solution than any here is to use a [`GameComponent`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.gamecomponent.aspx) (or [`DrawableGameComponent`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.drawablegamecomponent.aspx)) and [`GameServices`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.game.services.aspx). This would allow you to be able to grab the `Player` object without needing a hard reference to it at all times. Instead, you only need a reference to the `Game` object.

*Other references*

- http://www.nuclex.org/articles/4-architecture/6-game-components-and-game-services
- http://www.innovativegames.net/blog/blog/2008/10/09/engine-tutorial-1/